# using keyword running in scala test

Tags: scala, scalatest

when i attempt to run a fake application in a scala test based off of some article the keyword running isn't recognized.  Is running part of a scala library?

```
"be retrieved by id" in {
  running(FakeApplication()) {


  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the whole code you hav for the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a part of [Play Test API](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.12/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.Helpers$@running[T](testServer:play.api.test.TestServer)(block:=>T):T)

You need to import it:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers._
```

And make sure it's in your project's dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-test_2.11" % "2.5.12"
```